# Laravel: Relation empty after using `whereHas` and `with`?

Tags: laravel-5, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

I have this query:

```
 $user =  \App\User::where('id','=',191)
            ->whereHas('addresses', function($q){
              $q->getByDistance(52.5293878, 13.3416309, 5);
            })
            ->with(['addresses' => function($q){
              $q->getByDistance(52.5293878, 13.3416309, 5);
            }])
            ->get();

dd($user);
```

This picks the user with id `191`, only if he has an address in range, and then he also eager loads the address.

This is the `scopeGetByDistance` function from the class `addresses`

```
public static function scopeGetByDistance($query,$lat, $lng, $max_distance)
{
  return $query->selectRaw('lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( '.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance')
               ->having('distance', '<', $max_distance )
               ->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' );
}
```

I picked the user with `id` 191 because I know that he has an address with distance ~2 to the coordinates.

This will output a user, but the relation is empty. Shouldn't  the `whereHas` make sure that the relation is not empty? I also know for sure that he must have an address in range. This is how the relation looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code of `scopeGetByDistance()`. Does the relationship work when you just use `->with('addresses')`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have improved the question and added also the `scopeGetByDistance()` function. Yes if I just use `with('addresses')` everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the reference key to the `selectRaw` like this:

```
return $query->selectRaw('user_id, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos
```